# How to escape "<" character in password inside PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

Here's my script:

```
@rasdial "My VPN" "user@domain" 'my<password'
```

My password contains `<` character. This, without `@` works when entered into PowerShell console.

I know `` ` `` is the quoting character, but obviously it doesn't work with `<`.
My password contains many special characters so it has to be quoted. But it doesn't work when double quotes are used. How to escape the password properly? Is there a way to import it from an external file? BTW, rasphone.exe remembers my password, maybe is there a way to use it?

---

Here's the solution I found working. I used double quotes instead of single quotes. It didn't work at the first time, because there was also `%` in my real password, which needed to be quoted with `%%`.

So, inside .cmd script: `` 'my%`<password' `` won't work, but `"my%%<password"` will.

Can anyone confirm he used string like `` '...`<...' `` inside .cmd script and it worked? Does it behave differently in different PowerShell versions? Mine is from Windows 8 x64.

Comment: What exactly is this line : @rasdial "My VPN" "user@domain" 'my<password' Its not a script by itself.

Comment: Why, doesn't a single command count as a script? I've created a cmd file to log me into VPN every time I log into Windows 8. I pointed this file as an action for Task Scheduler. It works as charm now.

Comment: This is a .cmd file??? .cmd is batch not Powershell.

Comment: You're right! Geez, my fault. I mixed it. I don't know, I made so many mistakes in that question, that I wonder if maybe I should delete it? What do you think?

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue and it took me a while to get to the bottom of it. In my case I had a password similar to this

> }K)/]j..|{?*&%($@7}e$%0>;._#

Putting it in double quotes allows for variable expansion so obviously that wont work.
Putting it in single quotes is supposed to work but didn't for me. Escaping problem characters with the back tick also didnt work for me.

What worked for me was to surround with single quotes first and then double quotes

> '"}K)/]j..|{?*&%($@7}e$%0>;._#"'

Comment: I have searched long and hard for this, with many incorrect answers. Deserves many upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
'my`<password'
```

` <--- The tilde key backquote is the Powershell escape character.

I would also encourage using -AsSecureString

Testing in the PS console:

```
PS C:\Users\Athomsfere> $pw = 'my<password'
PS C:\Users\Athomsfere> write-host $pw
my<password
```

So its not the character by itself.

It still woks like this too: (As a script)

```
'@rasdial', "My VPN", "user@domain", 'my<password' |`
    ForEach
    {
        Write-Host $_
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried? I have (as the first thing) and it didn't work.

Comment: ` is a grave accent. `~` is a tilde.

Comment: @alroc yes it is, I was clarifying that its on the tilde key, the ` is also known as the backquote (Don't ask why, I just see it referenced as such)/

Comment: There may be keyboard layouts where the ` and `~` are not on the same physical key. ` is also known as a "backtick" in some circles.

Comment: I apologize all of you for poor formatting of my example which could be misleading. I fixed it now. I didn't know how to properly quote the "backtick" using "backticks" in SO ;) It's hard to ask question about quoting, because you have to quote quoted characters in it ;)